# How to filter multiple variables in a data.frame/data.table in Shiny with various combinations

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

If I have a data.frame/data.table with multiple columns needed to be filtered and, later passed to other calculations, how can I filter the data without creating multiple combinations of filtering conditions using `if else`.

For example, if I have a data with Age, Gender, Ethnicity, and created three `selectInput()`.

What I would like to achieve is that,

1. If I select Age: `10-19` from the drop down list, then this should be passed to the data and do `DT[Age %in% "10-19"]`
2. Similary, if I select Age: `10-19` and Gender: `Female`, then these should be passed to the data as `DT[Age %in% "10-19" & Gender %in% "Female"]`
3. If I deselect `Age`, then the data will return Gender: `Female`, such as `DT[Gender %in% "Female"]`

How can I capture those conditions, and pass to the data filter automatically without explicitly going through those combinations?

Here is a non-working testing example

```
df <- data.table(AgeGroup = sample(c("0-9", "10-19", "20-29"), 20, replace = TRUE), 
                 Sex = sample(c("Male", "Female"), 20, replace = TRUE))

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("AgeGroup", "Age Group", choices = c("", unique(df$AgeGroup))), 
      selectInput("Sex", "Sex", choices = c("", unique(df$Sex)))
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # How to modify here so that we don't need to do
  # `if (input$AgeGroup) df[AgeGroup == input$AgeGroup]`
  # consider multiple filters, some filters are selected and some are not. 
  # For example, if there are 5 filters, there would be 2^5 combinations
  
df_out <- reactive(df)
  
  output$table <- renderTable(df_out())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I really think a minimal reproducible example would help here. What category of your inputs is preselected? The first? A category called `"all"`? The solution to your problem depends in part on those questions.

Comment: I usually put `choices = c("", Age)` for NULL selection as the first choice.  I don't know how to make it work in the `server` function, but the description should be clear for my intention. Otherwise, I have modified the question for a non-working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `|` and `&` to build a filter statement. The trick is to say `input$a` is either `""` (which means return all rows) **or** `a` is `input$a`. You can use `%in%` instead of `==` when using multiple input values.

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(a = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                 b = 1:3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("a", "Select A", choices = c("", c("a", "b", "c"))), 
      selectInput("b", "Select B", choices = c("", c(1, 2, 3)))
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  df_out <- reactive(df[(input$a == "" | a == input$a) &
                        (input$b == "" | b == input$b),])
  
  output$table <- renderTable(df_out())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

A more programmatic solution is to use `vapply()` and wrap the result in `rowMeans()`:

```r
library(shiny)
library(data.table)

df <- data.table(a = c("a", "b", "c"), 
                 b = 1:3)

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("a", "Select A", choices = c("", c("a", "b", "c"))), 
      selectInput("b", "Select B", choices = c("", c(1, 2, 3)))
    ), 
    mainPanel(
      tableOutput("table")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  
  
  df_out <- reactive({
    
    idx_vec <- vapply(c("a", "b"),
                              FUN.VALUE = logical(nrow(df)),
                              FUN = function(x) {
                                input[[x]] == "" | df[[x]] == input[[x]]
                                })
    
    df[rowMeans(idx_vec) >= 1,]
    
  }) 
    
  
  output$table <- renderTable(df_out())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't want to do that if there are multiple filters. Some would be applied to the data, some would not.  For example, if there are 5 filters, there would be 2^5 combinations.

Comment: I'm not quite following, if you have five inputs, you have five `(input$x == "" | col_nm == input$x)` statements. How do we end up with 2^5 combinations?

Comment: Say 5 variables, `a, b, c, d, e`, each with a `selectInput()` filter. It could be `(a==input$a)`, then `b, c, d, e`variables won't be filtered. It could be `(a==input$a) & (c==input$c)`, filters won't be applied to variable `b, d, e`. Then if nothing is selected, then it returns the `df` itself, and etc.

Comment: I added a more programmatic solution, but I still don't get my head around the 2^5 issue. Maybe you can take my example and show me a case where it is not producing the desired output.

Comment: Brilliant, this is solution I am looking for. Thank you.  As for 2^5. Just considering 3 variables, then 2^3 combinations. 1. nothing gets selected, 2. one of them gets selected (=3), 3. 2 of them get selected (=3), then all get selected (=1).  = 8.